# How can I delete the '0' from my date day in django (python)?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I am creating a django application and I have the next problem: I have a date (for example "June 3, 2001") and I can't convert that string to date, because it doesn't exist a format directive in python to refer to a day without '0'

How can I caonvert that to "2001-06-03"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dateutil` by installing `pip install python-dateutil`

Then

```
>>>from dateutil import parser
>>>mydate = "June 3, 2001"
>>>str(parser.parse(mydate).date())
'2001-06-03'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime.strptime , if you are using python -

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("June 3 , 2001" , "%B %d , %Y")
d
>> datetime.datetime(2001, 6, 3, 0, 0)
```

Please understand that `%B` (notice capital B) -> stands for complete month names (like January / February / June)

If you would be using the 3 letter abbreviations instead (like Jan / Feb / Jun) , use `%b` .

To get back the date in the format you ask for use `datetime.strftime` , like below -

```
d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
>> '2001-06-03'
```

If you have to use both formats for month names, You can first try using one format, and catch an exception, if that fails use the other format. Example -

```
from datetime import datetime
try:
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime("June 3 , 2001" , "%B %d , %Y")
expect ValueError:
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime("June 3 , 2001" , "%b %d , %Y")
d
>> datetime.datetime(2001, 6, 3, 0, 0)
```

Comment: the problem is that %d is not correct for the day, because the day "3" has not '0' (I mean, it is not "03"); so I have an error. "time data 'June 6, 2010' does not match format '%b %d, %Y'"

Comment: Like I said in the post (Please read it carefully) , use `%B` , not `%b` (Capital B) , the issue is not with the `%d` .

Comment: '0' is not a problem, just try the line in a console and you will see.

Comment: time data 'June 6, 2010' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'

Comment: Like I said use only one format, either three letter abbreviations through out or full names through out

Comment: There is a space in - `'%B %d , %Y'` , `%d` and `,`